Not able to Mock constructor defined outside of the React Component using Jest
I have an issue with a test with jest mock.
The question is simple why I'm not able to properly mock the constructor if I define it outside of the component?
(*)In this example, I'm using reactQuery but this scenario is unrelated to this.
import * as reactQuery from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';

//If I place here the definition of the client it doesn't work
const client = new QueryClient();

const TestComponent = () => {
  //<--- Instead if I place it here (inside the component) it works. Why???

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={client}>
      <div>Some Component</div>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
};

jest.mock(`@tanstack/react-query`);

it(`Test`, () => {
  const constructorSpy = jest.spyOn(reactQuery, `QueryClient`);

  render(<TestComponent />);

  expect(constructorSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();

  /*
    Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
   */

});


Thanks for the help.

I don't know why you use jest.mock() and jest.spyOn() together. Below solution only uses jest.mock():
test-component.test.tsx:
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';

const client = new QueryClient();

export const TestComponent = () => {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={client}>
      <div>Some Component</div>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
};

jest.mock(`@tanstack/react-query`);

it(`Test`, () => {
  render(<TestComponent />);
  expect(QueryClient).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

Test result:
 PASS  stackoverflow/78678507/test-component.test.tsx
  √ Test (9 ms)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.032 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

